# Fixed div interfering with navbar bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set a fixed header title below the main navbar, but it is interfering with de options of the navbar,

here the code

```html
<style>
  .titlefixed {
    z-index: 1030;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
  }
</style>

<div class="titlefixed " style="background-color:white;">
  <blockquote>
    <h2><em>Sucursales</em></h2>
    <hr />
    <h2><small>@Model.Name - @Model.Client.RazonSocial</small></h2>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

and this is what's happening

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLcz1.gif)

Thanks if anyone can help me to solve it

Comment: an image to your code doesn't help at all. Please edit and include your code.

Comment: Adjust the `z-index` to be below the value of the Bootstrap Navbar / Dropdown components.

Comment: Which value you think would be correct ?

Comment: I just tried a few values and it works. Thanks @RobertC